# Control eBay notifications

Tags: ebay

Is there any way to control which notifications appear in the upper right corner (notifications bell icon with drop-down) and/or flyouts on the right?

Specifically, I'd like to disable "ENDING SOON - GET IT NOW" notifications for Watch list items (that are generally regularly re-listed anyway) and "OUTBID" notifications (also the flyouts on the right; the point of entering a maximum bid and using the automatic bidding system is that if someone else bids higher than that I would not want to outbid them).

Under My eBay -> Account -> Site Preferences -> General Preferences there may be a section titled "Buying Alerts on eBay pages," and there are settings here but they don't seem to stop either flyouts or alerts in the upper right.

[image]

I can't find anything else under My eBay -> Account -> Site Preferences or Communications Preferences, which seem to be more about e-mail or instant messenger or app notifications, but maybe I'm missing something.